# Python How to influence running program

Tags: python, kivy

Button **Start alarm** starts ringing of alarm. I want to stop ringing by button **Stop alarm**. I don't know to influece running program. How must I repair function **stop_alarm**?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import winsound

class ControlPanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # make sure we aren't overriding any important functionality
        super(ControlPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.alarm_status = True
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        butOn = Button(text = "Start alarm: ", on_release = self. start_alarm)
        butStop = Button(text = "Stop alarm: ", on_release = self.stop_alarm)

        self.add_widget(butOn)
        self.add_widget(butStop)

    def start_alarm(self, obj):
        while self.alarm_status == True:
            winsound.PlaySound("alarm.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    def stop_alarm(self, obj):
        self.alarm_status = False

class LifeApp(App):
    def build(self):     
        return ControlPanel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LifeApp().run()
```

Comment: what is not working now ?

Comment: `start_alarm()` has an endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you have a while loop on your main GUI thread. So what you need to do is to run the start_alarm on a different thread than your main GUI thread for the GUI thread to be responsive.

As for not being able to play alarm next time, you didn't set the alarm_status flag to True again.Once you have that you can start and stop the sound as many times you want.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import time
import winsound
import threading

class ControlPanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # make sure we aren't overriding any important functionality
        super(ControlPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.alarm_status = True
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        butOn = Button(text = "Start alarm: ", on_release = self.start_thread)
        butStop = Button(text = "Stop alarm: ", on_release = self.stop_alarm)

        self.add_widget(butOn)
        self.add_widget(butStop)

    def start_alarm(self, obj):
        while self.alarm_status == True:
            winsound.PlaySound("alarm.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        #Set Alarm_Status True so that next time it works
        self.alarm_status = True

    def stop_alarm(self, obj):
        self.alarm_status = False

    #Function to run your start_alarm on a different thread
    def start_thread(self,obj):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.start_alarm,args=(obj,))
        t1.start()

class LifeApp(App):
    def build(self):     
        return ControlPanel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LifeApp().run()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You. Your advice is for me great help, but I have one question still. I cann't repeat start of alrm after pressing of button Stop alarm. Can you explain to me this problem?

Comment: I have edited the answer to support that now. The problem was that the alarm_status flag wasn't set to True, so that it could play next time.

Comment: Thanks! I am ashamed now. Brain works in bends sometimes.